# Loading and using javascript and jquery in web services

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

We are using an HTML parser called [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) in our .NET web services. We parse some HTML pages using this parser and extract some content. Though this parser is useful, we are looking for better productivity. We are wondering whether we can load javascript and jquery in web services and use jquery just like we use it on web pages for extracting content. This would make our job a lot easier.

If we cannot do this, Can we leverage the power of jquery in some other way? We are really curious to know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the HTML content to the user's browser and parse it with jQuery there.
Then show it to the user.
Or, if needed for others, post the result back to the server to cache it.

Comment: This does not work as the user will be using an iPhone application.